# Append draft email body then send using EWS API & PowerShell

Tags: powershell, exchangewebservices

So I've got pretty close with this but no cigar yet.  I'm wanting to find a draft email based on subject string then append to the existing body.  I've managed to find all drafts, update the body of one of them and save it but I'm stuck on filtering a specific message out by subject.

I've tried various PowerShell wizardry on $draftEmails[0].Subject but I can't stick that object into a string with just the subject line to do any comparison operators on it.  I either need to convert this object to something I can work with or filter when I do FindItems.  Imagine I'll have similar issues when trying to update the body as I'm just replacing with a whole new body here.

Can somebody point me in the right direction?

```
# Install EWS
Install-Module -Name EWS -MaximumVersion 1.1.5 -MinimumVersion 1.1.5 -confirm:$false -force
Add-Type -Path 'C:\Program Files\WindowsPowerShell\Modules\EWS\1.1.5\lib\Microsoft.Exchange.WebServices.dll'

# Create Exchange service object
$service = New-Object Microsoft.Exchange.WebServices.Data.ExchangeService -ArgumentList Exchange2013_SP1

# Add url of Exchange Web Services api
$service.Url = 'https://outlook.office365.com/EWS/Exchange.asmx'

# Add credentials for sending user
$service.Credentials = New-Object Microsoft.Exchange.WebServices.Data.WebCredentials -ArgumentList  "user@email.com", "password"

#Bind Drafts folder
$WellKnownFolderName = [Microsoft.Exchange.WebServices.Data.WellKnownFolderName]::Drafts
$Drafts = [Microsoft.Exchange.WebServices.Data.Folder]::Bind($service, $WellKnownFolderName)

# Find items in Drafts folder
$ItemView = [Microsoft.Exchange.WebServices.Data.ItemView]::new(99999)
$draftEmails = $Drafts.FindItems($ItemView) 

# Load extended properties of found items
$psPropset = new-object Microsoft.Exchange.WebServices.Data.PropertySet([Microsoft.Exchange.WebServices.Data.BasePropertySet]::FirstClassProperties)  
[Void]$service.LoadPropertiesForItems($draftEmails,$psPropset)

# Show all draft emails with extended properties
$draftEmails

# Update body on first draft
$draftEmails[0].Body.Text = "Hello World"
$draftEmails[0].Update([Microsoft.Exchange.WebServices.Data.ConflictResolutionMode]::AutoResolve)
```

Comment: "I've tried various PowerShell wizardry on $draftEmails[0].Subject but I can't stick that object into a string [...]" - `$draftEmails[0].Subject` is _already a string_, so what exactly are you trying to accomplish here?

Comment: $draftEmails.Subject.gettype() is definitely not a string.  If it was I could work with that.

Comment: why not just do | Where-Object {$_.Subject -eq 'test'} ?

Comment: I don't think that operator will create a match Glen.  Think its because $_.Subject isn't a string.  I've tested this on a very basic example but its been a while now so will have another go but still haven't solved this.

Comment: I'd like to apologise to the entire StackOverflow community I was comparing my email subject to a different string.  "Test is a test" vs "This is a test".  I'd down vote myself but it wouldn't let me.